# Assign object into unordered_map array?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

```
typedef tr1::unordered_map <string, pin *> pin_cmp;
pin_cmp _pin_cmp;
_Pins[_num_pins] = new pin (pin_id, _num_pins, s, n, d);
_pin_cmp[_Pins[_num_pins]->get_name ()] = _Pins[_num_pins]; //performance profiling
```

Could you teach me what actually the code doing?

```
_pin_cmp[_Pins[_num_pins]->get_name ()] = _Pins[_num_pins]; //performance profiling
```

I am not familiar with unordered_map which still can use with array[].I am confuse unordered_map just need key and value why will have array[]?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In the last line you just create(or change) element with `Key = _Pins[_num_pins]->get_name ()` and `Value = _Pins[_num_pins];`. Could you, please, clarify the question a bit?

Comment: @soon
Hi soon,actually I totally dont understand what is the last line doing._Pins[_num_pins] is a class object. _Pins[_num_pins]->get_name = return pointer to _name which is "htclk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above example I expect `_Pins` to be a sequential container.

`_pin_cmp[_Pins[_num_pins]->get_name ()] = _Pins[_num_pins]; //performance profiling`

This line of code accesses a element `_Pins[_num_pins]` twice:

1. On the right handside to get the object
2. On the left handside to get the name of the object.

Then the object is placed inside `_pin_cmp` (unordered map) using the name of the object as index.
Exact behavior of this operation is described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator%5b%5d/).

Comment: Hi.Thx for ur reply.So let say if _Pins[_num_pins] is a pointer to an object and _Pins[_num_pins]->get_name () is to get _name and return pointer to _name.
So now what is my key and what is my value?
_name will be my key and _Pins[_num_pins] will be the value?

Comment: The name-string will be your key, the pointer to your object will be the value.

Comment: Let me make sure I am clear.
So there is char* get_name(){ return _name//_name = htclk }.
So now _Pins[_num_pins]->get_name () will have the pointer to _name
and _Pins[_num_pins] is a pointer to object.
So is _pin_cmp[htclk] = pointer to object or
_pin_cmp[pointer to htclk] = pointer to object ? Hope you understand what i trying to say. :)

Comment: Because you are using std::string (as can be seen in `tr1::unordered_map <string, pin *>`) the pointer to _name will be converted to a std::string object in the map. You can access the object by calling _pin_cmp["htclk"], which will search for a std::string that equals "htclk" and returns the value at that location.

Comment: Wow.Totally understand now.Thanks you very much :)

Comment: FYI accessing std::string with a char* works because std::string has a implicit conversion from char*. For information look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast